# SVG Image is not uploaded in WordPress dashboard

Tags: wordpress, image, svg, file-upload, wordpress-theming

Here I am using WordPress with the updated version.

I have faced an issue with image uploading. When we upload the SVG format images in the media library, it shows as an empty box view. It seems like an issue in storing the image. We are using the SVG support plugin to smooth upload for SVG images.

Note: Other formats like PNG, JPEG is working properly, when I uploaded them to the media library. Only facing issues in SVG format.

Please refer to the attached image for reference,
[image: It looks like empty image]

Comment: Have you tried contacting the developer of the plugin about this? If anyone can answer this question it's surely them.

Comment: @cabrerahector, sure , Il try that..!